# Is there any book avaiable for Expression Blend 4?

Tags: expression-blend

I want to learn expression blend in detail. is there any good book available in the market for Blend4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expression-Blend 4(expression -Studio) was released less than one month.(exactly 29 day). So there is no any book available now .
But 2 book come early and u can check them when they are released:
1) Foundation Expression Blend 4 with Silverlight by Victor Gaudioso (released time: Aug 31 2010) by appress
2) Expression Blend 4 Unleashed by Brennon Williams (released time: Nov 15, 2010) by sams

Answer (score 0):

I've found Expression Blend in Action by Joel Cochran to be excellent. It's written from a developers point of view (rather than a designers).

http://manning.com/cochran/